# Kein öffnendes Anführungszeichen, nur schliessendes. Geht das?

Tags: punctuation

Ich habe einen Zeitungsartikel mit der folgenden (für mich verwirrenden) Struktur 
 gefunden:

> **Titel**
>   *Untertitel*
>
> [Zitat]**“** [Neuer Satz, der den Autor des Zitats nennt.] (...)

Das heißt, ein Anführungszeichen schließt, was nirgendwo geöffnet wurde. Erwartet habe ich also

> **Titel**
>   *Untertitel*
>
> **„**[Zitat]**“** [Neuer Satz, der den Autor des Zitats nennt.] (...)
>      ⇧

Ist das stilistisch so gewünscht? Ist es bloß ein Tippfehler? Ist es üblich?

Comment: Schlichtweg ein Druckfehler. Natürlich gehört an den Anfang des Zitats das Anführungszeichen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regeln des Rechtschreibrats § 89

> Mit Anführungszeichen schließt man etwas wörtlich Wiedergegebenes ein.

*ein*schließen kann man nur zwischen Pärchen. Das ist ganz einfach ein Fehler.

Comment: Es scheint mir, dies auch im Englischen gesehen zu haben – zumindest dass die Anzahl der öffnenden nicht mit den schließenden übereinstimmt. Somit wäre dies wohl ein syntaktischer „falscher Freund" des Englischen. Es nervt irgendwie (Kontext: https://www.xkcd.com/859/).

Comment: Es ist natürlich nicht auszuschliessen, dass englische Autoren manchmal dieselben Fehler machen wie deutsche.

Comment: Das Englische hat eine Konvention, bei der ein langes Zitat das öffnende Anführungszeichen am Anfang jedes Absatzes wiederholt. Dadurch gibt es tatsächlich eine abweichende Anzahl. Das ist aber ein rein englisches Phänomen. Imitation im Deutschen wäre ein Anglizismus.

Comment: @KilianFoth Ich weiß nicht wieso ich anstelle Anglizismus „falschen Freund“ geschrieben habe. Ich meinte die von dir erwähnte Imitation.

Comment: @KilianFoth Habe ich auch schon gesehen.Diese Konvention ist dann allerdings eher eine typographische (damit off-topic) als eine der Zeichensetzung.

Answer (score 8):

Zeitungsartikel beginnen gerne mit einem großen [Initialbuchstaben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initiale). In dem Fall, dass der Artikel mit einem Zitat anfängt, dann kann durchaus ein öffnenes Anführungszeichen weggelassen werden:

> „Beginnt der Text bei Verwendung von eingebauten Initialen mit einer Anführung, entfällt sie. Nur bei freistehenden Initialen, ob sie stumpf beginnen oder nach Einzug, kann man die Anführung aus der Grundschrift vor die Initialen setzen, und zwar, wie gezeigt, in der Größe der Grundschrift.“ 
>   
>   
> *Forssman/de Jong: "Detailtypografie" (S. 288)*

Sollte der Zeitungsartikel mit einem Inital gedruckt werden, könnte es durchaus sein, dass es deswegen entfernt wurde.